# Cannot compile project when declaring a XAML Resource Dictionary in code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, xaml

I've got a `Resource Dictionary` called EditorResources.xaml and it contains the following code:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:editors="clr-namespace:MyCompany.Editors">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="PasswordEditorDataTemplate">
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But when I include this line of code in a class:

```
private EditorResources res = new EditorResources();
```

It doesn't compile my project. I doesn't display any `Errors List` view in the `.NET IDE` but when I look at my `Output` view, it displays the following error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'EditorResources' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But, I don't believe the reference is missing as both the resource dictionary and class are in the same project (same level) and I can clearly see the `EditorResources` type highlighted as `Type` and `IntelliSense` kicks in as expected when I hit my '.' key and it displays properties relevant to a `Resource Dictionary` i.e. `.MergeDictionaries`, etc...

**UPDATE:**

if like me, you've stored your resource dictionary (editorresources.xaml) in a sub-folder (Editors), and your assembly is called 'MyCompany.Activity.Shared' for example, don't forget to include the sub-folder in the component's part so that when you call the code provided by @DrewNoakes, you can call the following without any problems:

```
var res = new ResourceDictionary
{
   Source = new Uri("/MyCompany.Activity.Shared;component/editors/editorresources.xaml",
   UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
};
```

Once you have your object, you can access your DataTemplates or other via code.

Comment: Did you try to clean the project and re-build it or restart VS?

Comment: Having an `EditorResources.xaml` file doens't mean that there is a **class**  `EditorResources` that you can instantiate. Do you know how to work with the resource dictionaries in code? (Not sure about that why you'd gonna need this anyway...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have a `EditorResources.xaml` file but not a corresponding `EditorResources.xaml.cs` file.

In this case, the type your XAML file defines is `ResourceDictionary`. If you wish to have a subclass of that, you need to define the partial backing class and add the relevant attributes in the XAML to link them together.

If you don't need any C# code behind the scenes, just load the `ResourceDictionary` directly.

Some code like this might help:

```
var dict = new ResourceDictionary
{
    Source = new Uri("/YourAssemblyName;component/EditorResources.xaml",
                     UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
}
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but I'm getting `An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code - Additional information: Cannot locate resource 'editorresources.xaml'.` I've set my assembly with and without ".dll" but to no avail. Do I have to set the EditorResources.xaml to another type i.e. Embedded?

Comment: Yes you'll need to experiment with the file type. Might be `content` or `embedded resource`, I can't recall.

Comment: Still not working! I've found other links on stackoverlow stating the same solution as yours and I've tried the various suggestions but still no luck! Pain, but I'll keep looking. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try changing the path used in the `Uri`, along with the `UriKind`. If it's in the same assembly, maybe use `"EditorResources.xaml", UriKind.Relative`.

Comment: Cracked it (by fluke!). I was about to give up and decided to go with the Partial class option but it didn't like `InitializeComponent` in the partial's class constructor but when I pressed F12 to see if my InitializeComponent actually existed in the base class it brought me to the EditorResources.g.i.cs and in there it contained the full `Uri`. I had my dictionary and the class trying to access it in a sub-folder called Editors, so the full path had to be `Source = new Uri("/MyCompany.Activity.Shared;component/editors/editorresources.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)`.